# How to stop error propagation in an Angular interceptor

Tags: angular, error-handling, interceptor

I have a http interceptor in my Angular app:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  intercept( req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next
      .handle( req ).pipe(
        tap(event => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            Logger.log('Successful HTTP request in interceptor');
          }
        }, (error: any) => {
          const notFoundError = ErrorCodes.getErrorDescription(error.status);
          if (notFoundError) {
            this.messageService.show(errorMessage);
          } else {
            return Observable.throw( error );
          }

        }
      ));
  }
}
```

When there is a notFoundError, my app correctly shows the message I want, but it seems the error propagates back to the error handler in the service and I get a 
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse" in the console. Is there a way to stop errors in an interceptor?

I mean I would handle common errors here and only propagate others back to the services.

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing this with rxjs 6:

```
import {EMPTY} from 'rxjs';

//in your try/catch, interceptor, if statement, etc. 
return EMPTY;
```

From documentation:

> Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and
>   immediately emits a complete notification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to return empty from Observable?

```
if (notFoundError) {
   return Observable.empty();
} else {
   return Observable.throw( error );
}
```

Comment: I got Property 'empty' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable, so I imported 'rxjs/add/observable/empty'; and same thing.    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:   in console

Comment: In my components, I am importing empty with import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';

Comment: hmm, no luck :(

Comment: Guess it has something to do with the tap operator, will investigate further

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
intercept (request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error.status === 401) {
        alert('Please log in.')
        return throwError(null)
      }
      return throwError(error)
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: This will just continue the error propagation with an empty error.